# BeautifulSoup webcrawling: How to get piece of text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, html-parsing

The page I am trying to crawl is http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=1&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2013&p=.htm. Specifically, I am focusing on this page right now: http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman3.htm.

For each of the movies on the first link, I want to get the Genre, Runtime, MPAA Rating, Foreign Gross, and Budget. I am having trouble getting this because there is no identifying tag on the information. What I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=' + str(page) + '&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2013&p=.htm'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.select('td > b > font > a[href^=/movies/?]'):
            href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')
            title = link.string
            print title, href
            get_single_item_data(href)


def get_single_item_data(item_url):
    source_code = requests.get(item_url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    print soup.find_all("Genre: ")
    for person in soup.select('td > font > a[href^=/people/]'):
        print person.string


trade_spider(1)
```

So far, this retrieves all the titles of the movies from the original page, their link, and a list of the actors/people/directors etc. for each movie. Right now I am trying to get the Genre of the movie.

I tried to approach this in a similar way as the

```
"for person in soup.select('td > font > a[href^=/people/]'):
        print person.string"
```

line, but this isn't a link, it is only text, so it is not working.

How can I get this data for each of the movies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `Genre:` text and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find(text="Genre: ").next_sibling.text
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [3]: response = requests.get("http://www.boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=ironman3.htm")

In [4]: soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

In [5]: soup.find(text="Genre: ").next_sibling.text
Out[5]: u'Action / Adventure'
```